# vb.net repoting how to recover deleted xml file

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I accidentally deleted my xml file for a report. I now get the error : root element is missing. How can I recover my file ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your recycle bin? If its not there and you don't have a back up you got two options:

1) Some sort of File Recovery Software like "EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Professional"

2) System Restore